# ImportError: No module named django_libs.models_mixins

Tags: django, django-forms

I am getting the following error:

ImportError: No module named django_libs.models_mixins

Does somebody know how to fix this? I am a django noob...

Comment: looks like you don thave the 3rd party app `django_libs` installed

Comment: Could you point me to the command to install these 3rd party django_libs or the specific one necessary to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install django-libs
```

and then add it to your installed apps in the settings.py file.